# Entity Framework 6.2 generate nested query with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-6

I have this code:

```
int limit = 500;
int orderId = 123456;

var db = new Context();
var result = db.Orders.Where(x => x.OrderID == orderId)
        .OrderBy(x=> x.OrderDate)
        .Take(limit);
```

The sql code generate is:

```
SELECT TOP (500) 
[Project1].[OrderID], 
[Project1].[OrderDate], 
[Project1].[AccountID]
FROM (SELECT
[Extent1].[OrderID], 
[Extent1].[OrderDate], 
[Extent1].[AccountID]
FROM [Orders] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[OrderID] = @p__linq__0) AS [Project1]
ORDER BY 
[Project1].[OrderDate]
```

But if I change the code, like this:

```
int limit = 500;

var db = new Context();
var result = db.Orders.Where(x => x.OrderID == 123456)
        .OrderBy(x=> x.OrderDate)
        .Take(limit);
```

The sql code generate is:

```
SELECT TOP (500) 
[Extent1].[OrderID], 
[Extent1].[OrderDate], 
[Extent1].[AccountID]
FROM [Orders] AS [Extent1]
WHERE 123456 = [Extent1].[OrderID]
ORDER BY 
[Extent1].[OrderDate]
```

I am using Universal PredicateBuilder (Pete Montgomery’s Universal Predicate Builder ) to perform dynamic queries, so I need the generated sql code to be like the last one shown. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: What "issue" is it you're trying to resolve? Does the code *not work*? Does it produce a wrong result? It's not very clear what you're trying to "solve" here....

Comment: In general you have no control over ORM generated SQL. If you have performance issue (different execution plans), it's more likely because the first query is using parameter and the second - constant. Subquery should not be an issue with nowadays  SQL query optimizers.

Comment: Thanks @IvanStoev, I need the "order by" to run together with the "where" but using variables. Do you have any idea how to solve that?

Comment: Still don't understand why you need that - are you modifying the generated SQL? Anyway, it's not solvable at LINQ level - as I said in the previous comment, you can't control EF generated SQL.

Comment: I don't think it would matter all that much, but I think you just need to change the order a bit:

    var db = new Context();
    var result = db.Orders
            .OrderBy(x=> x.OrderDate)
            .Take(limit).Where(x => x.OrderID == orderId);